# Mongodb how to add a custom field in projection clause if an array of ojects contain specifc value

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Suppose I have a company collection, each post document may have a field `followers`, which is an array of objects, like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a82831c0b74a9276c3f826c"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2018-04-07T11:42:15.490Z"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-02-13T06:18:04.630Z"),
    "name" : "MY First post",
    "description" : "One the best IT solution company",
    "follows" : [ 
        {
            "userId" : ObjectId("5a82b527fe741c1854fcabe8"),
            "_id" : ObjectId("5ac8ae9724f44d7e88d8d7f0")
        },
        {

           "userId" : ObjectId("5a82831c0b74a9276c3f826b"),
           "_id" : ObjectId("5ac8aa818e932c05e0bc4af3")
        }
    ],
    "likes" : [],

    "owner" : {
        "id" : ObjectId("5a82831c0b74a9276c3f826b"),
        "firstName" : "User",
        "lastName" : "One"
    },
    "createdBy" : {
        "id" : ObjectId("5a82831c0b74a9276c3f826b"),
        "firstName" : "User",
        "lastName" : "One"
    },
    "status" : 1
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a939bce456ea36f18de80ad"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2018-04-07T11:51:09.407Z"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-02-26T05:31:58.918Z"),
    "name" : "MY second post",
    "description" : "Afghanistan Development Registry And Services is a co-governance company.",

    "follows" : [],
    "likes" : [],
    "owner" : {
        "id" : ObjectId("5a939bce456ea36f18de80ac"),
        "firstName" : "Aslam",
        "lastName" : "Popal"
    },
    "createdBy" : {
        "id" : ObjectId("5a939bce456ea36f18de80ac"),
        "firstName" : "Aslam",
        "lastName" : "Popal"
    },
    "status" : 1
}
```

Now I have the following query:

```
db.getCollection('companies').aggregate([
  {"$match":{"status":1}},
  {"$project":{
      "follows":1,"benefits":1,"totalRatingAverage":1,
      "reviews":{"$size":{"$ifNull":["$reviews",[]]}},
      "isInMyFollowing": {$eq: ["$follows.userId", ObjectId("5a82b527fe741c1854fcabe8")]}
  }},
  {"$sort":{"name":-1}},
  {"$skip":0},{"$limit":10}
])
```

Now I want to add a field to my selection result to show is each company followed by me or no?

I have updated my data sample, please check again.

Comment: Tell one thing: https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8GWi.png 
`Now I want to add a field to my selection result to show is each company followed by me or no?` -> Now whats meant by the field `isInMyFollowing`  how different it is from what you wanted?

Comment: @RahulRaj with my query, it returns `isInMyFollowing: false` for both records, but as you can see, my first document is followed by a user. At main my current query returns the wrong result.

Comment: added an answer for you (fix + workaround )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a close check, found that your `$follows.userId` actually returns an array instead of `ObjectId("5a82b527fe741c1854fcabe8")`.

`"test" : [ 
        ObjectId("5a82b527fe741c1854fcabe8")
    ]`

**Update:**
Try this query that compares with right value of `ObjectId`:

```
db.getCollection('sample').aggregate([
 {"$match":{"status":1}},
 {"$project":{
  "follows":1,"benefits":1,"totalRatingAverage":1,
  "reviews":{"$size":{"$ifNull":["$reviews",[]]}},
  "isInMyFollowing": {$in: 
 [ObjectId("5a82b527fe741c1854fcabe8"),"$follows.userId"]}
 }},
 {"$sort":{"name":-1}},
 {"$skip":0},{"$limit":10}
])
```

And it gives me output:

```
/* 1 */
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5a82831c0b74a9276c3f826c"),
"follows" : [ 
    {
        "userId" : ObjectId("5a82b527fe741c1854fcabe8"),
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ac8ae9724f44d7e88d8d7f0")
    }, 
    {
        "userId" : ObjectId("5a82831c0b74a9276c3f826b"),
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ac8aa818e932c05e0bc4af3")
    }
],
"reviews" : 0,
"isInMyFollowing" : true
}

/* 2 */
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5a939bce456ea36f18de80ad"),
"follows" : [],
"reviews" : 0,
"isInMyFollowing" : false
}
```

Comment: But your query brings the wrong result when a company is followed by more than one person. Suppose this company is followed by two other people, now when me, or two other visits this company profile `isInMyFollowing` is true, but this query returns false

Comment: You are not bringing your proper data set,  so assumptions can get restricted. Please post fully qualified json data set with all data variant documents.

Comment: I have updated my data sample. It's working only for the first follower, not for others.

Comment: And also your query output remove array from follows and in response follows changes to object, not an array of object.

Comment: Updated the query, check it and let me know.

Comment: One another final question, how we can add an extra check to `isInMyFollowing` field, to check if `follows` field exists check, else set it as `false`?

Comment: After you **stole my answer**, you forgot to remove your explanation of how you used `$unwind` and `$addFields`.

Comment: Shame on u downvoting my answer for this. Response posted on your post. Dont want to argue further,  move on..

Comment: Agreed. SO isn't for arguments. I only bothered to comment because your explanation and code were so different, which you've fixed. You can get your information from wherever you like.